# Who decides what goes into "gem install <gem_name>" and how do you decide which fork to use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, github

Such as for `delayed_job`, there is tobi's version and collectiveidea's version.

> http://github.com/tobi/delayed_job
>   http://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

Who decides what goes into `gem install delayed_job`?  (Does rubygems.org's contain all the official ones?)  And if we use anything directly from GitHub, how do we decide which fork to use -- such as tobi's or collectiveidea's version?

Answer (score 1):

Whomever checked in the gem to rubyforge.org controls what is in the gem.

Added: here is an [overview](http://newgem.rubyforge.org/) of adding a gem to the rubyforge repo.

But often you may want to use a gem that is not in rubyforge.org. You can do that too. You can have your own repository of gems if you want; or download the gem and install locally (no repo).

Re which fork of a popular project should I use?

Check the readme's of the forks, change files, etc. Try to determine which is the most tested, current, etc.

Also ask in the forums/groups/community that supports the project.

Welcome to delayed_job, it's great.